# data is showing undeifne in the react post method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am try to get the data from the express server. i am getting the data perfectly if i print the data. but if i try to print the data.name or data._id than it's showing the undefine and same condition with the state (book.name or book._id).

here is the code

```
function GetBookData() {
  const [book, setBook] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getBook() {
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/books");
      const data = res.data.data;
      setBook(data);
      // const params = useParams();
      console.log(data.name)
    }
    getBook();
  }, []);
```

how to access the value from the data